# Having trouble with files requiring root access

Tags: apt, 16.04, package-management, mongodb

First I would like to point out Im a total Ubunutu Noob:

Im trying to install MongoDB, however at one point or another i messed it up and created a wrongly named file, it was supposed to be called " mongodb-org-3.0.list " and thanks to a typo now i have a file named " mongodb-org-3.0.list3 "... anyhow, everytime i try doing something in the console i get the following message and I never get through doing what I intended to do...

N: Ignoring file 'mongodb-org-3.0.list3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

any help solving this issue?...

I already tried switching users see if it might go away... even re-installing Ubuntu Desktop as a whole but I get the same message no matter what I do...

Answer (score 3):

Just rename the file to remove the last `3`:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list{3,}
```

this will strip off the last `3` from file name `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list3`.

On the other hand, if you do not want the repository(ies) from that file from being included in `apt`,  give it a `.bak` extension:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list{3,.bak}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list3 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

That will rename the file to `mongodb-org-3.0.list`.